# Why does my Netbeans Xdebug session timeout after period of inactivity

Tags: php, debugging, netbeans, timeout, xampp

I love the way the Netbeans helps me to debug my Magento applications (in XAMPP on Win 7 64-bit), but I've noticed that the connection seems to timeout after a period.  The breakpoints no longer get hit and I have to restart the debugging session which is annoying. Any suggestions for how to extend or disable the debug timeout?

I can't see any options in the IDE or Xdebug php.ini config.  The Xdebug documentation states:

> When the URL variable
>   XDEBUG_SESSION_START=name is appended
>   to an URL, Xdebug emits a cookie with
>   the name "XDEBUG_SESSION" and as value
>   the value of the XDEBUG_SESSION_START
>   URL parameter. The expiry of the
>   cookie is one hour.cookie is one hour.

but doesn't suggest how to change the expiry time.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Find php.ini and add the following line to the xdebug section.

```
xdebug.remote_cookie_expire_time = 3600
```

The number is the time in seconds for the cookie to remain active, which defaults to 3600 (1 hour). I set it to 36000 (10 hours), which works fine and encourages me to restart the process occasionally to free memory. You can set it to 0 (unlimited) if you want, although I found that caused odd freezes here and there.

Remember to restart Apache for the change to kick in.

Comment: /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini (path as hint for linux users)

Answer (score 8):

This is probably related to your Apache-Configuration.

The probable cause is a configured timeout that defines after what period of time the server ends the process if nothing happens ... makes sense usually, but when debugging you might be just busy taking a look at something.

My setup is somewhat different from yours but maybe I can help you.

In the apache-folder /sites-available are located the files that configure your domain-related virtual hosts. Within the -Tags of your Domain and protocol **I** put

```
<IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
     AddHandler fcgid-script .fcgi
     IdleTimeout 300
     IPCConnectTimeout 20
     IPCCommTimeout 120
     IdleScanInterval 120
</IfModule>
```

That increased **in my case** the available period of time until the timeout would be triggered from 40 to 120 seconds.

Then (of course) restart your apache.

Maybe that helps.

Comment: I had the same problem as Jonathan, this worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: This seems to be related to the time the browser waits idle for the web server to respond, while the question is about the lifespan of the xdebug session, 1 hour by default.  
I'm having the problem this answer targets, so I'll give this a try.

Comment: Yes! Thank you! After months of dealing with this I finally found the right combination of search terms to lead me to this answer! Newer versions of apache / mod_fcgid use the directive `FcgidIOTimeout` instead of `IPCCommTimeout`. I set mine to *300* for a monster 5 minute debugging session. I agree this is an answer to a different problem than the OP's but it's an answer to my problem so I'm happy.

Comment: FcgidIOTimeout did the trick for me (it was set to 64 somewhere I found it, and changed it) Lukes comment should be made into an answer!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I solved it by changing **FcgidIOTimeout** instead of **IPCCommTimeout**.

In a ***Linux*** environment:

find :

`sudo grep -rnw '/etc' -e 'IfModule mod_fcgid.c'`

**Result**:

/etc/apache2/someconfiguration:34:

/etc/apache2/mods-available/fcgid.conf:1:

Find this line:

`<IfModule mod_fcgid.c>`

```
FcgidIOTimeout 45
```

`</IfModule>`

Add/change to:

`<IfModule mod_fcgid.c>`

```
FcgidIOTimeout {some time value you want: 3600}
```

`</IfModule>`

Answer (score 0):

For those who're using php-fpm try increasing value of `request_terminate_timeout` in your php-fpm ini file.