# How to increase timeout for xDebug when debugging a php script

Tags: php, vim, xdebug, vim-plugin

I have a long script that I need to debug using the terminal (more than 300K lines).

Unfortunately after a minute or less it gives me a time out error message before reaching a breaking point.

This is the error message I get:

```
Connection closed, stop debugging (<class 'socket.timeout'>, timeout('timed out',), <traceback object at 0x248c9e0>)
```

I use Vim in order to debug, it works fine when the break points are closer to the script's beginning.

I searched the [documentation](http://xdebug.org/docs/all) but I couldn't find where to set the time out.

UPDATE:

I use this [plugin](https://github.com/ludovicPelle/vim-xdebug) for vim and my xDebug version it's 2.1.0

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4139794/why-does-my-netbeans-xdebug-session-timeout-after-period-of-inactivity

Comment: I don't think so, I think that `xdebug.remote_cookie_expire_time` it's only for the browser and anyways it defaults to 1 hour, and my time out is in a minute or less.

Comment: what exactly is your xDebug plugin and version?

Comment: I've updated the question in order to provide this information.

Comment: Was an answer found to this? I am having this same issue. I set a break point in my code and before it can get to that break point it times out. I am debugging a magento application and so it has to go through a lot before it gets there.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure this out - in ~/.vim/plugin/debugger.py, line 666 or around there

```
socket.setdefaulttimeout(5)
```

change this to something more

```
socket.setdefaulttimeout(15)
```

this has the effect of changing the timeout from five seconds to 15 seconds, which for me was enough but for you maybe you want to change it to

```
socket.setdefaulttimeout(30)
```

for 30 seconds.

Also - the 5 second timeout in waiting for Xdebug connections was annoying me pretty bad so I changed it to 15 too - this was on my line 556

```
serv.listen(15)
```

Then also, i wanted the little connect message to also reflect this, so I updated this (trivial) on line 551

```
print 'waiting for a new connection on port '+str(self.port)+' for 15 seconds...'
```